# Keep in-line equation inside page margin

Tags: margins, siunitx, inline

While using the excellent [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package, I noticed that part of an inline expression exceeds the page margin. Reverting to conventional representation of numbers, I still observed that part of the expression is crossing the right margin. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch,doublespacing]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{siunitx} % All the SI unit nomenclature
  \sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr, output-complex-root = j, complex-root-position = before-number}

\newcommand{\E}{\varepsilon}  % epsilon

\begin{document}

Next, we consider the lossy case where the permittivity of metal layers is $\E_m = \num{-143.4967 - j 9.5173}$ and the compared results are shown in Figure 1 and listed in Table xyz.

Next, we consider the lossy case where the permittivity of metal layers is $\E_m = -143.4967 - j 9.5173$ and the compared results are shown in Figure 1 and listed in Table xyz.

\end{document}
```

which compiles to:

[image: result]

I would like the inline expressions to respect page margins.

Comment: Reword the sentence. Or set the maths on a separate line as display. Or break the expression up. Bad solution: use \sloppypar or tell TeX it is OK to break before the equation. Or similar. To put this another way, what do you want TeX to do here?

Comment: I thought that TeX would automatically enforce margins, and that is what I want.

Comment: It doesn't enforce margins. It isn't Word. It tries to respect margins. You will find warnings in your output notifying you that TeX could not find a good line-break in this case.

Comment: You could make it respect margins no matter what. (Well, except in cases where a box exceeds the text width all by itself.) But you don't want to do that because the no-matter-what will result in other kinds of ugliness, such as large amounts of space between words.

Comment: If I increase the font size to 12pt, I get the intended (expected) result. I wonder how TeX figures in that case, or it may be a coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding the `microtype` package will automatically correct this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch,doublespacing]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{microtype}  % <======

\usepackage{siunitx} % All the SI unit nomenclature
  \sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr, output-complex-root = j, complex-root-position = before-number}

\newcommand{\E}{\varepsilon}  % epsilon

\begin{document}

Next, we consider the lossy case where the permittivity of metal layers is $\E_m = \num{-143.4967 - j 9.5173}$ and the compared results are shown in Figure 1 and listed in Table xyz.

Next, we consider the lossy case where the permittivity of metal layers is $\E_m = -143.4967 - j 9.5173$ and the compared results are shown in Figure 1 and listed in Table xyz.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks AboAmmar for bringing up the microtype package. From the first look, it seems to be one of the packages, that should always be present in the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

"sloppypar" also solved this issue

```
\begin{sloppypar}Next, we consider the lossy case where the permittivity of metal layers is $\E_m = \num{-143.4967 - j 9.5173}$ and the compared results are shown in Figure 1 and listed in Table xyz.
```

\end{sloppypar}

Answer (score 0):

\allowbreak works for me. Example: $a = x+y\allowbreak (z-1)$.